No Gravity in my Gazebo Fortress sim
Im using ROS2 Humble with Gazebo Fortress, and loading everything up using this launch file. Despite this, theres no gravity, when I move it to start above the ground it doesn't fall down, I also dont move when I start up a teleop_twist_keyboard to publish some twist messages for my diff drive plugin. I think its just for some reason not simulating any forms of motion, any ideas why?
